# Strategy for finding OSGi bundles

Tags: osgi, bundle

What is your strategy for finding bundles when developing OSGi applications?

This is how I do It and I think it's kind of troublesome in some ways.

When I need a reference to lets say:

```
GroupId: group.name

Artifact: artifact.name
```

I fire up add maven dependency in Eclipse and search for it and add it to my pom, start using it and everything is fine, source code wise.

But when I deploy my bundle to my container and install group.name/artifact.name/1.2.3 I sometimes have some bad luck and the referenced bundle isn't a bundle but a simple plain jar.

Here is where I start google for a bundle of group.name/artifact.name. Downloading pom.xml to see if there is a maven-bundle plugin in the build. Downloading the jar and see if there are any export-packages in manifest.mf and so on.

Is there a better strategy for this? How to find OSGi-bundles easy?

What is your way of doing OSGi development?

Comment: In my mind, this is one of the major problems using OSGi. This is exactly the same way I do this, since I do not know how to do this better.

Comment: You could just use [pax-wrap](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol) at runtime - it uses BND to turn plain Jars into bundles via a URL handler when you install.  A very simple elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/

It's a repository of "bundlelized" libraries. There are a lot of libraries and you can be sure that the transitive dependencies of a library are also bundles

Comment: Thats a good one, have used it alot. But sometimes it fails me too :)

Answer (score 3):

I've created an experimental site that holds all of maven central, ebr, and more. You can look specifically for bundles adding osgi:* to the query.

[https://jpm4j.org/#/search?q=osgi:*](https://jpm4j.org/#/search?q=osgi%3a%2a%5d)

Again, this is experimental for now but feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got two more :-)
One place always worth taking a look at is the servicemix project, it got lots of osgi-fied libraries. Another one is the ops4j pax tipi project. Big advantage of both projects, you'll find those artefacts at maven central, so no extra repository to add to your project.

Comment: I've used the servicemix bundles alot, they are great!